# How can an object have more than 3 degrees of freedom?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, degrees-of-freedom

In 1 of my robotics classes our professor told us that something can have up to 6 degrees of freedom:translation in the x axis , translation in the y axis,translation in the z axis,rotation around the axis,rotation around the y axis and rotation around the z axis.

However any point in 3d space can be described by 3 numbers:$r,\theta,\phi$ so any action can be described as:$\Delta r,\Delta \theta,\Delta \phi$.So there cannot be more than 3 degrees of freedom for any object since if there were,we would leave our 3d space.What am I missing

Comment: Objects are not points. Points are described using three degrees of freedom, but real objects are *extended*, and can rotate independently of their translational motion.

Comment: Objects are a set of points and if you acted on each point of a object independently , you would get the same object if you acted on the object as a whole.

Comment: Because the number of configurations of the arm is not the same as the number of spatial points that the arm can reach. You can have many arm configurations that reach the same point. The more complex the arm the larger the number of configurations.

Comment: Yes the number of configurations < number of spatial points.

Comment: no, the number of configurations is larger than the number of points in space. Imagine a simpler problem, you want to describe the configuration of two particles moving independently in space (they might be attached by a spring, or satisfy some other constraint, but that doesn't change the situation much). Then you need 6 degrees of freedom to describe the state, 3 for each particle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your professor is talking about representations of the position and orientation of a rigid body. Those two things combined have exactly six degrees of freedom in 3D space. You need three degrees of freedom just to specify the location of a dimensionless point. But most rigid bodies are more interesting than that. We also are interested to know which way the body is *oriented.* You need three more degrees of freedom to specify orientation.

Imagine an airplane. Which direction is it facing (what is it's magnetic compass showing?), North? South? East? 272.8°? The compass heading counts for one degree of freedom. But then, is it banked to the left? is it banked to the right? That's another. And, is it nose-up? nose-down? That's a third. Add to that the latitude, longitude, and the altitude; and now you've got six numbers to account for.

If a robot needs to know the position *and orientation* of some rigid, physical object in its environment, it's the same deal. You need at least six numbers† to represent it.

---

† In practice, the software may use as many as sixteen numbers if it represents position and orientation as [*transformation matrices*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix) in a [*projective space*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_geometry). Or, it may use as few as seven numbers if it represents position as a vector and orientation as a [*quaternion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion). While it is possible for software to use only six numbers (three position coordinates, plus three [*Euler angles*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles)), that often ends up being more complicated in the long run, because the software then must employ special-case strategies to avoid [singularities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_(mathematics)) in the math. (see also, [*gimbal lock*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock)).

Comment: Hi!Have a good day!Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The 3 degrees of freedom is only for a point object , for extended objects we need more to properly understand the orientation , like Mr Slow here has said , the aeroplane example is a good one .

Comment: Hi!Have a good day!Thanks a lot!